Efficient Hadamard product of matrix-matrix multiplication
I am trying to compute in Python the following operation: (AB).C, where A,B,C are sparse matrices, and with the lower dot " ."  I indicated the Hadamard (entry-wise) product of matrices,  and AB is the matrix-matrix multiplication between A and B. I need to perform this operation several times, with different matrices.
I am aware that everything could be done for instance as
import scipy.sparse as sp
# Example dimensions for non-square matrices
m, n, p = 1000, 800, 600
# Creating sparse matrices A, B, and D with different dimensions
A = sp.random(m, n, density=0.01, format='csr')  # Sparse matrix A
B = sp.random(n, p, density=0.01, format='csr')  # Sparse matrix B
C = sp.random(m, p, density=0.01, format='csr')  # Sparse matrix C for entrywise product
result = (A@B).multiply(C)

but this would end up in computing elements in the matrix-matrix multiplication that will later be multiplied by zero, therefore I believe there must be a more efficient way to do it.
I tried to store the sparsity structure of C and compute only the matrix-matrix product (AB) for the nonzero entrances (basically using nested cycles), but the result is terribly slower than just computing everything.

What is the typical sparsity of A, B, C? C being much more sparse than A, B demands a specific solution.

Additionally, do all three matrices change with equal frequency, or are some of them reused?

It's very difficult to beat scipy and numpy in efficiency. Many matrix operations are implemented in C, and any loops we write in Python will be slower than their C equivalents. However, it's possible to get a little bit of improvement depending on your sparsity and data size. I took some inspiration from this answer. Our method will be:

Use the .find() operation on C to know the indices which will eventually be needed.
Set all indices which will not be used to zero.
Drop all the zeros (this re-indexes the matrix).
Perform both multiplications on the new matrices.

import scipy.sparse as sp
# Example dimensions for non-square matrices
m, n, p = 1000, 800, 600
# Creating sparse matrices A, B, and D with different dimensions
A = sp.random(m, n, density=0.01, format='csr')  # Sparse matrix A
B = sp.random(n, p, density=0.01, format="csr")  # Sparse matrix B
C = sp.random(m, p, density=0.01, format='csr')  # Sparse matrix C for entrywise product

# 1. Find the non-zero indices
# The zipped pairs (a, b) contain each non-zero index of C
a, b, c = sp.find(C)

# 2. Set the non-used indices of A and B to zero
A[list(set(A.indices) - set(a))] = 0
B[list(set(B.indices) - set(b))] = 0

# 3. Eliminate the rows which are all zeros
A.eliminate_zeros()
B.eliminate_zeros()

# The final computation is the same
result = (A@B).multiply(C)

In my testing, it's quite hard to find a combination that runs significantly faster after dropping the rows. Your speed improvement will depend greatly on several factors:

If you need to do the multiplications for many matrices A,B with the same C, you only have to find the indices on C once. But if you have to re-calculate for different C matrices every time, my method will probably be slower than your naive method since you'll have to compute each time.
If A and B are very sparse, you won't get much benefit from dropping them. I found better results the higher the density of A and B and the lower the density of C. This makes sense, because we're using the information from C to skip more and more of the dot-product multiplication.

I didn't notice much difference at all when using your original values. I tweaked the densities as follows to show that this approach does yield speed improvements in the right situation. Note A,B have higher density and C has lower density than originally given. This is very dependent on your data, so play with it to see if you get any improvement.
m, n, p = 1000, 800, 600
A = sp.random(m, n, density=0.1, format="csr")
B = sp.random(n, p, density=0.1, format="csr")
C = sp.random(m, p, density=0.002, format='csr')

# Naive result
(A@B).multiply(C)
82 ms ± 6.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Result after dropping rows
(A@B).multiply(C)
47.1 ms ± 6.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

The easiest way to see if you'll gain some improvement is to compare the sparse matrices. Note the "stored elements" count.
# "A" before dropping rows
<1000x800 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 80000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

# "A" after dropping rows
<1000x800 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 62922 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Lastly, I'll mention that running timeit on your original densities showed negligible improvement. Only 8 rows were dropped out of 8000, so it's very data-dependent.

I was toying wuth making a 0/1 version of C, and using that to reduce A and B (via @).  Row and column sums could also be used (those too use @).  But all the preprocesing takes time, so it's only of use if it can be done once ahead of time.

Thank you for your help! I also got the impression that this type of computation is really data-dependent. I will try your suggestion on my data and hopefully I'll get some improvement :)

The CSR A.eliminate_zeros() step isn't cheap.  That's why it isn't performed automatically when values are set to zero. It requires rewriting the indices and indptr arrays.

You can write your own code which exploits the sparisity of matrix C
You wrote in your question, that you already have tried this, but without an example of your code.
I am also not sure if your test data even comes close to to actual problem, it takes about 0.5ms per run.
The benefit of a custom solution can heavily depend on the problem size and sparisity.
It is highly recommendable to give a realistic size and sparisity of the real problem. While some algorithms might be good at tiny problems, others may be some orders of magnitude faster in larger or more sparse cases.
The following example is actually much slower is C is quite dense, but competing with a BLAS routine is always difficult.
If writing a custom solution with a lot of loops, compiled code is clearly benefitial. In your case this can be straight forward implemented with for example Numba which only supports some parts of Python, or with some code changes Cython or just some wrapped C or Fortran Code.
In following example I used Numba, mainly because of simplicity.
Example
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def nb_calc(A_indices,A_indptr,A_data,B_indices,B_indptr,B_data,C_indices,C_indptr,C_data):
    res = np.empty(C_indices.size)
    res_ptr=0
    
    #Getting nonzero entries
    for i in range(C_indptr.size-1):
        for col_ind in range(C_indptr[i],C_indptr[i+1]):
            j = C_indices[col_ind]
            #Actual sparse vec/vec multiplication
            A_data_vec = A_data[A_indptr[i]:A_indptr[i+1]]
            B_data_vec = B_data[B_indptr[j]:B_indptr[j+1]]
            A_ind_vec  = A_indices[A_indptr[i]:A_indptr[i+1]]
            B_ind_vec  = B_indices[B_indptr[j]:B_indptr[j+1]]
                
            ii=0
            jj=0
            acc=0
            while ii < len(A_ind_vec) and jj < len(B_ind_vec):
                ind_A = A_ind_vec[ii]
                ind_B = B_ind_vec[jj]
                
                if ind_A<ind_B:
                    ii+=1
                elif ind_A>ind_B:
                    jj+=1
                    
                if ind_A==ind_B:
                    acc+=A_data_vec[ii]*B_data_vec[jj]
                    jj+=1
            res[res_ptr] = acc * C_data[col_ind]
            res_ptr+=1
    return res


def calc(A,B,C):
    C_indices =C.indices
    C_indptr = C.indptr
    C_data   = C.data
    
    A_indices = A.indices
    A_indptr  = A.indptr
    A_data    = A.data

    #algorithm works on csr(A),csc(B),csr(C) matrices
    B = B.tocsc()

    B_indices = B.indices
    B_indptr  = B.indptr
    B_data    = B.data

    res = nb_calc(A_indices,A_indptr,A_data,B_indices,B_indptr,B_data,C_indices,C_indptr,C_data)

    #create a sparse matrix
    res_sp = sp.csr_matrix((res,C_indices,C_indptr))
    return res_sp

The very same code with some modifications can also be written in Cython or C.
Timings
m, n, p = 1000, 800, 600
A = sp.random(m, n, density=0.01, format='csr')  # Sparse matrix A
B = sp.random(n, p, density=0.01, format='csr')  # Sparse matrix B
C = sp.random(m, p, density=0.01, format='csr')  # Sparse matrix C for entrywise product

%timeit (A@B).multiply(C)
%timeit calc(A,B,C)

526 µs ± 546 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
358 µs ± 639 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

data used by @grey_ranger
m, n, p = 1000, 800, 600
A = sp.random(m, n, density=0.1, format="csr")
B = sp.random(n, p, density=0.1, format="csr")
C = sp.random(m, p, density=0.002, format='csr')

%timeit (A@B).multiply(C)
%timeit calc(A,B,C)
16.7 ms ± 70.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
716 µs ± 2.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

